# ¿Cómo crear un nuevo vector divisible por 2, 3 y 6 simultáneamente?

Tags: java, array

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y hoy el profesor nos ha dado un código base:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Quiz4C {

static int i;
static Random r = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Lea = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Ingrese el orden del vector...");
    n = Lea.nextInt();
    int vec[] = new int[n];
    llenarV(vec, n);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Datos del vector ");
    imprimeV(vec, n);
}

public static void llenarV(int v1[], int j) {
    i = 0;
    while (i < j) {
        v1[i] = r.nextInt(98) + 1;
        i = i + 1;
    }
}

public static void imprimeV(int v1[], int z) {
    i = 0;
    while (i < z) {
        System.out.print(v1[i] + " ");
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Lo que el nos pide hacer con este código base es crear un nuevo vector con los valores divisibles por 2, 3 y 6 simultáneamente. Y por último encontrar la suma y promedio de los valores que no sean divisibles por su posición incrementada en 1. ¿Cómo se hace esto?

Comment: Debes intentarlo tu primero y luego hacer preguntas especificas.

Comment: Pista.  Debes modificar la funcion llenarV

Comment: Pistas: a) Un número divisible entre 6 lo es entre 2 y 3 
b) para saber si un número es divisible por otro  se usa la función módulo (% en java)

Answer (score 1):

### Teorema

Asumiendo que tu número es un número exageradamente grande, con más dígitos de los que puedes representar nuestro algoritmo aún podrá determinar la divisibilidad para cualquier número sin importar cuanto tienda este a un valor de magnitud infinita

### Lemmas

1. Criterio de divisibilidad entre 6: es divisible entre 3 y 2
2. Criterio de divisibilidad entre 2: el último dígito es par
3. Criterio de divisibilidad entre 3: La suma de sus cifras es múltiplo de tres

### Proposición (o Algoritmo en nuestro caso)

Primero obviamos el primer paso considerándolo trivial*.

Asumimos que el numero provisto es una cadena y obtenemos el último dígito<sup>1</sup>

```
String numeroEnCadena="12345";
char UltimoDigito=numeroEnCadena.charAt(str.length() - 1);
```

Corolario 1:

> el subconjunto obtenido está limitado únicamente a un valor en el subconjunto de los números naturales<sup>2</sup> consistente en {2,4,6,8}

Para detectar la divisibilidad de 3 procede a dividir el numero original en dígitos<sup>3</sup>

```
numeroEnCadena.split("\\d");
```

Posteriormente sumar los digitos<sup>4</sup> por pares, asegurándose que si la suma del par actual es mayor que `10` restar `10` para que se preserve como un número natural<sup>2</sup>

Corolario 2:

> podremos observar que incluso 9+9 = 18 es menor de 20 por lo que restarle 10 nos dejará un número natural<sup>2</sup>

### Notas

<sup>*</sup> ya que de todas formas lo haremos o mejor dicho no haremos mas nada si cumplimos las otras dos reglas

<sup>1</sup> esto te da la ventaja de que al comparación de caracteres es más rápida que la comparación de cadenas por lo que lo considero más eficiente que una solución basada en cadenas y en [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).

<sup>2</sup> Un número natural por definición es perteneciente al conjunto {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

3 donde \d representa un dígito y para escaparlo usamos doble diagonal.

4 luego puedes convertir cada dígito en entero mediante al función `parseInt`.

### Addendum

Addenda 1: No es la forma más eficiente de hacerlo en Java, (la forma más eficiente es con el uso de un operador como ya te dijeron en los comentarios) pero hay muchas formas de hacerlo, y ya que como no especificaste el desempeño, esta que te propongo es solamente una interpretación válida de la definición de las reglas que me enseñaron en la primaria.

Addenda 2: Agradezco personalmente que preguntaras como realizarlo en vez de como modificar tu código para realizarlo, esto nos permite responderte con teoremas y algoritmos que servirán para gente que programe en otros lenguajes.